# Find the residue of this function for all its isolated singularities

Tags: complex-analysis

> For $f(z) = \sin(z^2) / (z^4 + z^2)$, calculate its residue for all isolated singularities.

Anybody have hints for how to do this? I just cannot figure it out.

Obviously, the singularities are $0$, $i$, $-i$. But how to continue.

Comment: If you write $f$ as $f(z) = \sin z^2/z^2(z^2 + 1)$ you realize that the singularities are $z=0$ (multiplicity 2) and $z = \pm i$ (multiplicity one). Just calculate the residues for each pole https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis)#Limit_formula_for_higher_order_poles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The residue for $n$-order poles at $x=x_k$ is given by

$$\operatorname{Res}\left(f(x),\ x_k\right)=\frac1{(n-1)!}\lim_{x\to x_k}\left(\frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}(x-x_k)^nf(x)\right)$$

where $\frac{d^0}{dx^0}f(x)=f(x)$, and $\frac{d^n}{dx^n}f(x)$ is the n'th derivative.

For example, the pole at $z=i$ is order $1$, so we have

$$\operatorname{Res}\left(f(x),\ i\right)=\frac1{(1-1)!}\lim_{x\to i}\left(\frac{d^{1-1}}{dx^{1-1}}(x-i)^1f(x)\right)=\lim_{x\to i}\frac{\sin x^2}{x^2(x+i)}=\frac{\sin1}{2i}$$

The residue at $z=-i$ is also order $1$, and the residue at $z=0$ is order $2$.